# (R language) createDataPartition error --> "y must have at least 2 data points"

Tags: r, machine-learning, regression, partitioning

```
set.seed(1, sample.kind="Rounding")
test_index \<- createDataPartition(y = train$type, times = 1, p = 0.2, list = FALSE)
```

The dataset I am using is a collection of URLs, and "type" in "train$type" represents whether the URL is malicious or benign through zeroes and ones, respectively. However, having train$type as the y seems to be an issue when partitioning into 80/20 splits. The error message is "y must have at least 2 data points". How should I fix this? I'm guessing that I may have to restructure the data itself in the worst case scenario. Sorry in advance for my lack of experience with R!

I have tried adding "caret::" in front of createDataPartition, and none of the other related posts seemed helpful to my situation. Would be grateful for any help!

Comment: Maybe down or up sampling? Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?